# How to know if the command find any result?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

```
#!/bin/sh

LOOK_FOR="NTLMAuthenticationFilter"

for i in `find ./ -name "*jar"`
do
echo "Looking in $i ..."
grepjar -e $LOOK_FOR $i
done
```

I wrote the script above, and try to find if there any file name LOOK_FOR exist in those jar,my quest is: 
    grepjar -e $LOOK_FOR $i
here how can I check if there are any successful result , and output them ?

by the way, what's mean of $? in shell script ?
Thanks !

Comment: for i in `...` is a known pitfall, never do that. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following change:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOOK_FOR="NTLMAuthenticationFilter"

find ./ -name "*.jar" -print | while read -r FILE
do
echo "Looking in ${FILE} ..."
grepjar -e "${LOOK_FOR}" "${FILE}" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
RETCODE=${?}
if [ ${RETCODE} -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Found ${LOOK_FOR} in ${FILE}"
fi
done
```

The `?` variable stores the return value of the last command.  This will normally be `0` for success and any other value for failure.

You'll also notice that I've swiched the `for` command into a `while` command.  That allows for a larger set of returned results.

---

Breaking down that `find ./ -name "*.jar" -print | while read -r FILE` command:

`find ./` - starting in the current directory...
`-name "*.jar"` - find files ending in `.jar`...
`-print` -  and print their names
`|` - redirect that output to the next command
`while read -r FILE` - and while there is output from the previous command, assign it to the variable `FILE` and run the commands between `do` and `done`.

In other words, it takes the output of the find command (the list of files ending in `jar`) and runs the block of code in the loop.  For a short list it behaves exactly like your version using the `for i in` loop.  The advantage is that it supports long lists, since there's an upper limit to what you can pass on the command line, as you were doing with the `for i in` loop.

***Edit:*** Changed to bash script, changed style of variable quoting, included suggestions from comments and some other style changes.

Comment: -print | while read i, can you explain this ?   and I found that grepjar are always display error message, can I force it don't output any error message?

Comment: @Foolish: yes ...  `cmd 2> /dev/null`

Comment: /dev/null ?? any references ?  what does this mean ?

Comment: Anything in `/dev` is a device.  `/dev/null` is a special device that takes and discards any input.

Comment: If you're checking for `$?` being zero or non-zero in `if` then you're doing it wrong. Just put the command directly in the `if` in the first place.

Comment: @Ignacio - works fine that way and makes it clearer IMO what you're doing (admittedly I usually assign $? to another variable so I can then report on the exact return if it's non zero).

Comment: @Cry: Change `grepjar -e $LOOK_FOR $i` to `grepjar -e "$LOOK_FOR" "$i"`, and `read i` to `read -r i`, in case the file names contain special character backslashes. **Always double-quote variable substitutions** and pass `-r` to `read`, unless you know *why not*.

Comment: @Gilles - never heard of the `-r` option before, that's worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use $?.

In bash $? stores the return value of a command. You could check this value after the grepjar command and echo $i if it is what you are after.